# Finding the longest substring of several strings in java

Tags: java, compare, iteration, substring

I looked up for this 'finding the longest substring of several strings,' yet to find out several 'returning length of longest substring' and 'for two strings.' I do not know tree unfortunately and I thought of comparing two strings in advance and do for all pairs. After comparing, perhaps doing the preceded process should follow?

I didn't write any successful code yet. Thanks in advance..

This is the sample data and output.

```
3
AAAAAB
BAABC
CAAAABC
```

output is
    AAB

Comment: can you show some sample data and expected output? also, include an example where if two or more strings are equal length what has to be done.

Comment: "longest substring" -- substring based on what condition?

Comment: construct trie and do a depth first traversal and get the maximum length each time a word appears.

Comment: @Aominè I added the data and output. Thanks

Comment: @BikramjitRajbongshi Hmm.. I only thought of the length.. what are some other things to consider?

Comment: @svasa trie? If you are talking about 'tree' I have no idea.. And the length is not my aim..

Comment: [Longest common substring problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem) on Wikipedia might help you. If you don't want to use a tree then see the dynamic programming approach.